# Unable to connect to SQLite in C program under Windows 10

Tags: c, sqlite

Though there are a few earlier posts on this issue, I still can't find any right solution - any help is appriciated.

I followed [this instruction](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_installation.htm) and took the below steps for installation:

1. Downloaded precompiled binaries for Windows ([sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3240000.zip](https://www.sqlite.org/2018/sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3240000.zip)) form [sqlite.org/download](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html), and extracted to *"C:\sqlite"* folder

   Downloaded sqlite-shell-win32 ([sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3240000.zip](https://www.sqlite.org/2018/sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3240000.zip)) form the same download page, and extracted to the same *"C:\sqlite"* folder. This folder now contains sqlite3.def, sqlite3.dll and sqlite3.exe files.

   Added *"C:\sqlite"* in my PATH environment variable and the `sqlite3` command from my project folder *"C:\proj"* now works.

I then followed [this instruction](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm) and to run the program:

Code (test.c) saved under "*C:\proj*" :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h> 

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   sqlite3 *db;
   char *zErrMsg = 0;
   int rc;

   rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

   if( rc ) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      return(0);
   } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

In addition, since above code uses `#include <sqlite3.h>`, I downloaded [sqlite-amalgamation-3240000.zip](https://www.sqlite.org/2018/sqlite-amalgamation-3240000.zip) and extracted the "sqlite3.h" file to the same *"C:\sqlite"* location.

Command executed from *"C:\proj"*:

```
gcc test.c -o test -I\sqlite -l sqlite3
```

But I am getting below error:

> C:/prg/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: `cannot find -lsqlite3`
>   
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error, it's resolved now and for the benefit of others, here are the steps:

- Downloaded the one for 64-bit - [sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3240000.zip](https://www.sqlite.org/2018/sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3240000.zip) and extracted to *C:\sqlite* folder
- Converted the sqlite3.def file to sqlite3.lib by using Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 and executing `/def:sqlite3.def /out:sqlite3.lib /MACHINE:X64` command from *C:\sqlite* folder
- This time, the command `gcc test.c -o test -I\sqlite -L\sqlite -l sqlite3` from *C:\proj* folder was successful.

> Opened database successfully

Answer (score 0):

You tell `gcc` to look for header files in a non-standard location with the `-I` (upper-case i) option, but nowhere do you tell `gcc` to look for libraries in a non-standard location using the `-L` option.

If the libraries are in `C:\sqlite\lib` then add `-LC:\sqlite\lib` to the command-line before the `-l` (lower-case L) option.

Comment: Thanks I tried `gcc test.c -o test -I\sqlite -L\sqlite -l sqlite3` but no success. There's no sub-folder for lib under C:\sqlite and neither is there any `.lib` file as the 2 zip files don't have any

Comment: Thanks again as based on your suggestion, I was able to proceed further +1 for that